# Can one test Support v7 SearchView with Espresso on Android

Tags: android, android-support-library, searchview, android-espresso

I am doing some instrumented tests on my app in Android, but hit a wall. I have a SearchView which is from android's v7 support library, and I want to test this somehow. I guess its not directly clickable, since I tried it with conventional ways like:

```
onView(withId(R.id.search_view)).perform(click())
```

Is there any way to test such `SearchView` with Espresso?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The solution depends on the initial state of the `SearchView`.If it is collapsed, you have to open it first:

```
onView(withId(R.id.your_search_menu_id)).perform(click());
```

Then you can type into it.

There are two ways:

1. By search autocomplete id, which is public

   ```
   onView(withId(android.support.design.R.id.search_src_text)).perform(typeText("something"));
   ```
2. By using the fact, that it is `AutoCompleteTextView`

   ```
   onView(isAssignableFrom(AutoCompleteTextView.class)).perform(typeText("something"));
   ```

Comment: Is it inside overflow menu?

Comment: No, It is on the top sitting there itself.

Comment: No its just search_view

Comment: So change the id inside `withId` to the one in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for you help :) Can you delete the package name from your comment btw?

Comment: Is the solution from my answer working for you? Then accept the answer and give points so that other users know this is a valuable one.

Comment: I did now, forgot to do :) Thanks again for your help, and if it's not much trouble can you delete the package name from your earlier comment btw?

Comment: After you have entered the text to the SearchView you need to press the search button from soft keyboard, how do you do that? I tried the following with no luck:  `onView(withId(R.id.your_search_menu_id)).perform(pressImeActionButton());`

Comment: Please look into documentation of [typeText](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/action/ViewActions.html#typeText(java.lang.String)) : "Appending a \n to the end of the string translates to a ENTER key event"

Comment: If you have a SearchView as a widget within your layout you'll need to test input by first performing a click on the search button. `onView(withId(android.support.design.R.id.search_button)).perform(click());`

Comment: The solution works with support libraries. Nowadays AndroidX is a standard? Have you checked wrong import case?

Answer (score 1):

For some reason on `click()` doesn't work for me.

I used this extension of expression for searchViews, written in kotlin:

```
 class SearchViewActionExtension {

    companion object {
        fun submitText(text: String): ViewAction {
            return object : ViewAction {
                override fun getConstraints(): Matcher<View> {
                    return allOf(isDisplayed(), isAssignableFrom(SearchView::class.java))
                }

                override fun getDescription(): String {
                    return "Set text and submit"
                }

                override fun perform(uiController: UiController, view: View) {
                    (view as SearchView).setQuery(text, true) //submit=true will fire search
                }
            }
        }
        fun typeText(text: String): ViewAction {
            return object : ViewAction {
                override fun getConstraints(): Matcher<View> {
                    return allOf(isDisplayed(), isAssignableFrom(SearchView::class.java))
                }

                override fun getDescription(): String {
                    return "Set text"
                }

                override fun perform(uiController: UiController, view: View) {
                    (view as SearchView).setQuery(text, false)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

By calling `setQuery` with true for submit parameter it fires search right after.

Usage:

```
onView(withId(R.id.search_box))
            .perform(SearchViewActionExtension.submitText("search text"))
```

Answer (score 0):

for AndroidX

you can use Resource#getSystem to get the View

```
Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("search_src_text",
    "id", "android")


onView(withId(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("search_src_text",
"id", "android"))).perform(clearText(),typeText("enter the text"))
.perform(pressKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))
```